# W/Bundle: Key img expected Integer but value was a java.lang.String. The default value 0 was returned

Tags: java, android, android-volley

This is adapter.java

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        int position = getAdapterPosition();
        Data data = this.arrayList.get(position);
        Intent put_information = new Intent(this.ctx,Display_Gallery_item.class);
        put_information.putExtra("title_gallery" ,data.getTitle());
        put_information.putExtra("img" , data.getId());
        this.ctx.startActivity(put_information);

    }
```

Display_Gallery_item.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.display_each_item_gallery);

    iv_image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_gallery_item_show);
    tv_title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_show_each_item_gallery_Title);

    iv_image.setImageResource(getIntent().getIntExtra("img",00));
    tv_title.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("title_gallery"));

}
```

i cant get the title and pass to activity and show . but cant show image in imageview on Display_Gallery_item.java Please Help!!!!!!

Comment: What is `data.getId()`? Is it a resource id?

Comment: data is a object of Data Class (getter and Setter id)

Comment: getid() : to get image id from server

Comment: @Ahmed Hegazy      
data is a object of Data Class (getter and Setter id)

Answer (score 0):

This could be a cache conflict issue.

First, **Clean Project** from Android Studio.
Then, **uninstall the app** on your device, press **Run** from Android Studio.

The above steps helped me.